# CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing only in browser/jquery but OK with curl

Tags: javascript, jquery, tomcat, curl, cors

#### The problem is that I get different header responses in Browser vs Curl command

I've got mypage.com (client html/css/js) served by nginx on port 8081 in my local host.

I access it from a browser on http://mypage.com:8081 (mypage.com mapped to -> 127.0.0.1 on /etc/hosts).

#### Page loads fine and it does a first jQuery request.

```
GET http://mypage.com:8081/api/foo
```

I've got Tomcat 8 running my 2 REST APIs in port :9090

As target is :8081 request gets resolved in nginx

```
location /services
         proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:9090/services/
location /api
         proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:9090/api/
```

** =======Everything fine so far.==========**

#### Second request in JQuery is

```
GET http://mypage.com:9090/services/foo
```

As the current page in the browser is mypage.com:8081 and JQuery  call is targeted to mypage.com:9090/services/foo ; browser detects a CORS request.

In the request, 'Origin: http://mypage.com:8081' header **is set** but no Access-Control-Allow-Origin comes back. It simply does not.

```
OPTIONS http://mypage.com:9090/ returns 403 **ONLY in the browser**

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://mypage.com:9090/service/bar (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

I've checked Tomcat's configuration, added CORS filters and I can confirm through CURL everything is working fine when I execute the same command the browser does.

I'm running in circles with this one.
- CORS Origin header is set in both cases
- in Browser , result is 403 and response headers don't show anything else than

```
Content-Length: 87
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date: Wed, 23 Dec 2015 01:11:53 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

- in curl command though, same request produces a response where the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to the origin passed on the request header.

### Question : why browser OPTIONS returns no Access-Control-Allow-Origin? I can't seem to be able to reproduce it by hitting the same URL with the same verb with same arguments but through CURL command

Comment: make sure your other headers are whitelisted- curl doesn't enforce CORS validity like browsers do.

Comment: Does [`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Methods) permit `OPTIONS`?

Comment: Because browser and curl have different rules... [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) and [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: Thanks guys. Point taken. Browser and curl deal differently with CORS requests. My problem is still in the browser, that's what it matters. Access-Control-Allow-Methods does permit OPTIONS.  `<param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS</param-value>` . @dandavis what do you mean? I do have the following `<param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name><param-value>Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Origin, Accept,Last-Modified,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,X-AUTH-TOKEN</param-value>` **any other ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem at the end with this.

Following Tomcat's CORS flowchart I narrowed the problem to the fact there was a mismatch between the headers I was sending from the client and the ones supported in the backend.

The solution was to overwrite defaults in tomcat's filter by adding my custom header

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>....,X-My-Custom,...</param-value>
</init-param>
```